# Merging Batches of 200 Rows into 1 Row Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to merge 200 rows of a pandas dataframe into one row. The dataset consists of million of posts and i'm attempting to train a model on batches (profile level, instead of message level).

Image the next three lines are my pandas dataframe ( data['Body][:2] ):

```
line1 = "I'm a beast"
line2 = "Ofocurse, that's great"
line3 = "Hey John, what's up?"
```

I'm interested in obtain the following output, with the batch variable representing the first row of my batch pandas dataframe ( batch_data['Body][0] ) :

```
batch = "I'm a beast Ofocurse, that's great Hey John, what's up?"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, or is able to point me in a direction other than concatenating them one by one

Kind regards,

Sarah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lines':["I'm a beast", 
                           "Ofocurse, that's great", 
                           "Hey John, what's up?"]})
```

Just

```
>>> df.lines.str.cat(sep=', ')

"I'm a beast, Ofocurse, that's great, Hey John, what's up?"
```

The `sep` is the separator. you can change to whatever suitable

```
>>> df.lines.str.cat(sep=' ')
"I'm a beast Ofocurse, that's great Hey John, what's up?"
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response Rafael and i appreciate the answer. However, the output's separator has to be a space, not an additional comma as my model is highly sensitive to it.

Comment: I've just noticed how i've been an idiot for several hours. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @SahraLevre there's no such thing as stupid question ! :) To change the separator, just use the arg `sep` ! Ive edited to make it clearer

Comment: I've spend the last few hours trying insanely inefficients transformation, to find a solution that i had considered but i ended being to tired to think it through. Once again thank you very much!